# Understanding handlers on Ring and Appengine-magic (Clojure)

Tags: http, google-app-engine, clojure, httpwebrequest, ring

I started working on some clojure web apps and decided to use a combination of Ring + Compojure.
Recently I decided to try Google Appengine with AppEngine-magic (https://github.com/gcv/appengine-magic). However both appengine-magic (through it's start function) and ring's run-jetty function only take 1 handler as a parameter, I'm implementing several handlers and would like to know how to deploy them all.

Thanks in advance,
Ze

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's always going to be only one top-level handler -- after all, even if at some conceptual level there are multiple handlers, the app needs to decide which one to apply to a given request somehow, so the routine which makes the choice becomes the top-level handler. So, the short answer is that you need to provide a function which will look at a request and hand it off to the appropriate handler among the several handlers inside your app; that function is the handler to be given to `run-jetty` (or the equivalent).

Normally with Ring + Compojure you'd have some basic ("inner") handlers meant for handling particular URIs and some special-purpose handlers (say, for 404s) implemented as middleware. The former tend to be defined in `defroutes` forms, while the latter are higher order functions.

The middleware handlers decide for themselves -- after looking at the request -- whether they want to return a response immediately or to delegate to handlers they are wrapped around. The route-based "inner" handlers are called upon for appropriate URIs and have the option of returning `nil` to indicate that the request doesn't make sense to them (at which point the remaining route-based handlers are tried; if all `nil` out, the final response is normally generated by some piece of middleware, possibly returning a 404).

I've written a lengthy answer concerning Compojure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488353/whats-the-big-idea-behind-compojure-routes/3490479#3490479); perhaps it might be of some help in getting the hang of Compojure's route-based handler definitions.

Comment: Thanks, I was very tired and not thinking clearly :) That makes a lot of sense :) Funny enough I had tweeted your other post 1 day ago: http://twitter.com/#!/zemariamm/status/15553561278550016 Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best approach, I ended up implementing a ring.middleware function that wraps the other handlers around the main one:

```
(defn wrap-ohandler [f handler]
  (fn [req]
    (let [ res (f req) ]
      (if (= res nil) (handler req) res))))

(def handler-wrapped 
  (-> #'main-handler
    (wrap-ohandler #'anotherhandler )
    (wrap-stacktrace)
    (wrap-params)))
```

This works, but is this a good approach ?