# Clojure pattern matching

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching

I'm trying to implement http router with Clojure https://github.com/clojure/core.match library. But since match is macro - it seems that runtime update of routing table is'n possible without using eval, which is evil. Is there any cleaner way to this?

Comment: For HTTP routing, look at Compojure, Noir, or Moustache - probably best not to roll your own, one of those would probably suffice.

Comment: Eval is not evil if you have tight control over what it gets to eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alex said in the comments, you're going to want to check out [Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure).

Since you referenced routing in your question here is the [Routes in Detail](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Routes-In-Detail) section of the documentation.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488353/whats-the-big-idea-behind-compojure-routes) discussion on Stack Overflow about the "big idea" behind compojure routes.